# UNIX goes into unusable mode after typing certain commands such as CAT

Tags: unix, command, solaris, cat

I am new to UNIX so experiencing a little problem on Oracle SOLARIS 11 Virtual operating system for UNIX.

The issue is that after I type certain commands such as `CAT` etc. UNIX Command Line goes into an unusable mode after which no new command works until you manually close the terminal with mouse and restart again.

I want to know a way by which I can immediately continue working with next statements even if I type such commands like `CAT` (which make next commands not to work) without closing the whole terminal and restarting again. Respect for your precious time

I have a screenshot to make my problem easily understandable to you:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about programming. I assume it would be appropriate for the Linux & UNIX Stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to kill the cat process. Cat expects user input from stdin and that's the reason why the process won't stop unless you explicitly state that you want to stop it.

Check out [Unix signals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) for more information.

Comment: Yup! its working man thanks a lot but will it work with other commands also if I encountered one? Is Ctrl + C a general Hotkey?

Comment: Most processes serve the SIGINT signal (the one fired by the Ctrl+c combination) because it's a pretty important one as your experience confirmed! You can always try it in other processes and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

As already stated, Unix doesn't go in an unusable state but simply does what you asked it to do. Here `cat` is reading its standard input (keyboard) and displays it without further processing on its standard output (terminal).

There are a lot of other standard Unix utilities that read their stdin and write their stdout, this being the most common way to build complex commands from simpler ones under the Unix philosophy. The cleaner way to end the process is to enter the end of file character, commonly <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

While both <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will give you back the control of the command line, in the latter case the process is not interrupted but simply ends because it has nothing more to read.

Alternatively, should you do not want to end the process but recover the shell control anyway, you usually have the possibility to suspend the running process, and possibly put it later in the backgroud. You can do that with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and then the `bg` command.

Note also that sometimes processes are ignoring <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, if <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> doesn't work either, you can try sending the stronger `quit` signal, normally with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, which, in addition to interrupt the program will dump its binary image in a file (core) for later debugging.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case where actually you have not dealt with a command correctly and that has caused you terminal to go into an unusable mode, the answer provided by Sevle is the one to help you.

My answer is for the case where you have entered the correct command in the correct format, which got the command execution started, now the command is taking long to complete and give you back the terminal. In such scenarios where you know beforehand that some command may take long to finish, do the following

```
<command> &
```

what is does is to fire up the command and then push the process generated from the command in the background, so that you can get back the terminal for your subsequent work without having to wait for the command to finish. The above command would return you a process id which you can use to take the process to foreground once again if you need it.

Once you get back the terminal after firing command with '&' character appended, use the command

```
ps
```

to get the list of all the processes that are executing now. You will see you processes currently running in you machine, including the process for your command. You can use the process ID from this list or from the return value returned right after the command was fired, to get the process to foreground. Use the below command for that -

```
fg
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Let my reputation reach 15 and I will give you a thumbs up.......you deserve it. 

I have a question that if I need to work with some command then why will I need to kill it and make it as a background process? Won't I need that command to execute? I am a newbie so don't mind. Thanks

Comment: Thanks...happy to help :)  ... for your question, sending a process to background and killing the process are two completely separate things. Killing a process means to cause the process to stop to execute. Its like doing 'End Task' from Task Manager in windows machine. Sending a process to background means, just causing it to release the terminal and still making the process to continue executing in the background.

Comment: Regarding their respective needs.... say, you have to run a script which will process a file and would generate an output file. Now if the file in a big one, the script would probably take some time to process it. During the whole time, your terminal would get busy with that script, would not release the terminal and give you a prompt. Now in this situation you are not gaining anything from holding up the terminal as you are only concerned with the output file and that you will get only when the file processing ends. In this situation, we send the process to background and go on with next work

Comment: We kill a process when we no longer need it to execute. Like in the previous example, you have run the script and you suddenly realize that you no longer need to process the file. In this case, you kill the process for the script so that the script would no longer process the file.

Comment: Now I fully understood it. God bless you :)